# List the shipping city and state for the order that had the longest shipping delay

Tags: sql

List the shipping city and state for the order that had the longest shipping delay

I tried the following but cannot displayed:

```
TRENTON         NJ              4
```

as the only result that needs to be returned by the query.

```
select shipcity, shipstate, shipdate-orderdate "Shipping Delay"
from orders
having max(shipdate-orderdate) >any (select shipdate-orderdate
                from orders
                where shipdate is not null)
group by shipcity, shipstate, shipdate-orderdate;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming MySQL:

```
select shipcity, shipstate, (shipdate - orderdate) AS "Shipping Delay"
from orders
order by "Shipping Delay" desc
limit 1
```

If you really insist on subqueries, but of course the above works:

```
select shipcity, shipstate, (shipdate - orderdate) AS Shipping_Delay
from orders
where shipdate-orderdate = (SELECT MAX(shipdate-orderdate) FROM orders)
```

Comment: No I'm afraid that does not work. I'm suppose to use subqueries in order to get the longest shipping delay.

Comment: Is it calculated in any way? I don't see why you insist on subqueries.

Comment: @Anthony Oh, it is calculated. Thanks to your poor formatting it wasn't too obvious. Updated my answer. Please have a try with the first query again.

Comment: Poor formatting? I can't copy the entire thing here for it will not be displayed properly, that being said it works thanks.

Comment: @Anthony I just meant the missing spaces in shipdate-orderdate. Thought it was one column. Don't take it offensive.